# Xamarin AppUriHandler

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard, xamarin.uwp

I've been struggling with the APPUriHandler to work correct using Xamarin.Forms for building a multi platform app. I am not getting the AppHandler to work correct using the "Shared pages"

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-link i have managed to open the appif i launch the app manual, when using a link I get stuck on the SplashScreen
which throws an error : [image]

Its just when using the handler that it fails. I have identified that if I add a new page on the UWP project, and navigate to that page, it works fine. My problem is using the .Net standard (Old PCL) method as it is using multi platform. Is there a way to get past this or call the LoadApplication a different way from UWP MainPage as that is where it breaks

or anything that can steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the official code sample works in your side?

Comment: No, it gives the same error

Comment: Please share your system version.

Comment: Have tested in another computer?